# Casting Ado.net DataReader to IDataRecord giving strange result

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

I have a query that I run against the database, and I can see that there is a record for 31/05/2013.  When I run this query from C# with ADO.NET, and then use the following code, I am missing the record for 31/05/2013

```
var timeSeriesList = new List<TimeSeries>();  
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        timeSeriesList = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
            .Select(r => new TimeSeries
                 {
                     MidRate = (double)r["MidRate"],
                     RiskFactorName = (string)r["RiskFactorName"],
                     SeriesDate = (DateTime)r["SeriesDate"]
                 }).ToList();

    }
}
```

However, if I use the same query with this code:

```
var timeSeriesList = new List<TimeSeries>();                        
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var timeSeries = new TimeSeries
                 {
                     MidRate = (double)reader["MidRate"],
                     RiskFactorName = (string)reader["RiskFactorName"],
                     SeriesDate = (DateTime)reader["SeriesDate"]
                 };

        timeSeriesList.Add(timeSeries);
    }
}
```

...then the record at 31/05/2013 is in the collection - why would the first block of code give this result?

Comment: Did you mean to recreate the variable timeSeries within the While loop on 2nd example? I assume a typo?

Comment: The other fields what values they have? Of the record missing

Comment: @DaveRook, yes, sorry that is a typo

Comment: @christiandev, update your post, then I'll remove my comments  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you are missing record in first example because you move reader by one and then cast it.

Try this change and see if it worked:

```
var timeSeries = new List<TimeSeries>();  
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        timeSeries = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
            .Select(r => new TimeSeries
                 {
                     MidRate = (double)r["MidRate"],
                     RiskFactorName = (string)r["RiskFactorName"],
                     SeriesDate = (DateTime)r["SeriesDate"]
                 }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways of iterating through a data-reader; one is to keep calling `.Read()`; the other is to treat it as an `IEnumerable` sequence of `IDataRecord` and `foreach` it; no matter which you choose you can only iterate the data once.

- the call to `.Read()` moves from the BOF to the first record, if one

  - the `ToList()` calls `GetEnumerator()` then `MoveNext()` in a loop, which **immediately moves forward one position** (so we've dropped the first record on the floor without processing it); at the end of the `ToList()` we have chewed through all the data
- so the outer `.Read()` will then report `false` (EOF)

Basically: the problem here is using two APIs that progress the position. Either use `.Read()`, or use the `foreach` API (`.ToList()`).

As a side note, since the column names match the member names you could also use "dapper" to do the heavy lifting:

```
var list = conn.Query<TimeSeries>(sql, args).ToList();
```