# How can i Read data using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 database and I am working on it in the backend. I am working on asp.net/C#

```
using (SqlCommand StrQuer = new SqlCommand("SELECT *  FROM [shopcart].[dbo].[user] WHERE username=@userid AND password=@password", myconn))
{
   StrQuer.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", str_usr);
   StrQuer.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", str_psd);

   SqlDataReader dr = StrQuer.ExecuteReader();

   if (dr.HasRows)
   {
      // MessageBox.Show("loginSuccess");    
   }
}
```

I know that the reader has values. My SQL command is to select just 1 row from a table. I want to read the items in the row in the reader one by one. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: simply use dr["columnname"]

Comment: such type of questions i dont think should be answered here, very basic thing one can get answer at first search

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `FieldCount` property:

```
if (dr.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        var value = dr[i];
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018114/read-data-from-sqldatareader

Answer (score 1):

You can use dr.Read() inside while loop.

```
while(dr.Read())
{
    string firstCell = dr[0].ToString();
    string secondCell = dr[1].ToString();

    // and so on...
}

// It will be better if you close DataReader
dr.Close();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018114/read-data-from-sqldatareader

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    dr["NameOfColumn"].ToString();    
}
```

You obviously assign the variable and cast to appropriate type above.

Take a look at my question here too, for another solution [Casting Ado.net DataReader to IDataRecord giving strange result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916885/casting-ado-net-datareader-to-idatarecord-giving-strange-result)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dr.Read()` inside while loop. Like This :

```
while(dr.read())
{
    // MessageBox.Show("loginSuccess");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is full example of sqldatareader.

```
 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();  
        myConnection.ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString;  
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();  
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  
        myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories";  
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;  
        SqlDataReader myReader;  

        try  
        {  
            myConnection.Open();  
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();  
            while (myReader.Read())  
            {  
                ListItem li = new ListItem();  
                li.Value = myReader["CategoryID"].ToString();  
                li.Text = myReader["CategoryName"].ToString();  
                ListBox1.Items.Add(li);  
            }  
            myReader.Close();  
        }  
        catch (Exception err)  
        {  
            Response.Write("Error: ");  
            Response.Write(err.ToString());  
        }  
        finally  
        {  
            myConnection.Close();  
        }
```

Comment: This is a terrible example. There are no less than 3 `IDisposable` resources here and you `Dispose` none of them. Please read the fine manual for the `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Put the name of the column begin returned from the database where "ColumnName" is. If it is a string, you can use .ToString(). If it is another type, you need to convert it using System.Convert.

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
string column = rdr["ColumnName"].ToString();
int columnValue = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ColumnName"]);
}
```