# how to get SELECT * FROM TABLE results into more than one variable in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, select, sqlcommand

I have a table in DB with 3 columns and i have a SELECT query like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM Game WHERE gameID = " + game_id);
```

this table has: `gameID, Player1, Player2`.
my purpose is to get the players names `(Player1, Player2)` from the table into 2 variables in C# so i can use them to display in the form.
I tried to use the `cmd.executeScalar()` but it gets me only one result and not 2.

how can i do this please ?

Comment: Well what code are you using? You've shown us the query. Great. That's a start. What else? What code are you using to actually execute this on the database and read it's result? This alone, is not enough.

Comment: that was my question. how can i read the results into 2 variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, a few important recommendations:

- Do not use `SELECT *`. You might get back something different than what you thought (e.g. if the database schema has been changed in the meantime). Instead, specify each column that you're interested in explicitly.
- Instead of glueing together a SQL query using string concatenation, use a `@parameterized` query. This is a good principle to follow for reasons of both performance (query caching) and safety (preventing [SQL injection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) attacks).

So your code becomes:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Player1, Player2 FROM Game WHERE gameID = @gameId";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gameId", game_id);
```

Now to your question: How to receive the values of `Player1` and `Player2` of each record? That is where `IDataReader`s come in. A data reader is a forward-only cursor over the resulting table that allows you to access the values of each returned record:

```
// SqlConnection connection = cmd.Connection;
connection.Open();
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
{
    int player1Index = reader.GetOrdinal("Player1");
    int player2Index = reader.GetOrdinal("Player2");
    while (reader.Read())  // one loop iteration per record returned from SELECT
    {
        string player1 = cmd.GetString(player1Index);
        string player2 = cmd.GetString(player2Index);
        … // do something with player1, and player2
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ExecuteReader();` here's an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx). Also, take a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916885/casting-ado-net-datareader-to-idatarecord-giving-strange-result) here for how to read from **reader**

Answer (score 1):

Per the [`ExecuteScalar` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx):

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

You'll have to use `ExecuteReader` instead. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: why is it vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: @ShimritRevivo: Check out [this entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_implementation) on Wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

Consider using something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
{
    cnn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Game WHERE gameID = @gameID", cnn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gameID", game_id);
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var player1 = rdr.GetString(1);
            var player2 = rdr.GetString(2);
        }
    }
}
```

By using a block like this you get three things:

1. Access to the fields you want.
2. Protection from SQL Injection.
3. Proper disposal of unmanaged resources when connecting to a database.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cmd.ExecuteReader();` instead of  `executeScalar`